# Understanding the dual of a partially ordered set

Tags: order-theory

I would like to check my understanding regarding the dual of a partially ordered set $P$.

The dual of $(P,\leq)$ is defined to be $(P^*,\geq)$ which satisfies the property $$x\leq_{P} y\Longleftrightarrow x\geq_{P^*} y$$

I see that $(P^*,\geq)$ is also a partially ordered set. Looking at a lattice it is clear that the least upper bound of $P$ is the greatest lower bound of $P^*$, but proving it has got me confused.

Let $u$ be the least upper bound of $P$, then $$p\leq_{P} u\Longleftrightarrow p\geq_{P^*} u$$ This shows that $u$ is a lower bound of $P^*$. If $\alpha$ is any lower bound of $P^*$, how can we get that $\alpha\geq_{P^*}u$? Is the answer because $$\alpha\geq_{P^*}u\Longleftrightarrow \alpha\leq_{P}u$$ and $u$ is the least upper bound of $P$?

This leads into a bigger question that if $(P,\leq)$ has the supremum property wouldn't we be able to see $(P^*,\geq)$ also having the supremum property? (I believe my answer above will prove this result).

Thank you for looking!

Comment: Your reasoning seems right to me, but since the dual transform lower bounds into upper bounds, if $(P,\leq)$ has the supremum property, then $(P^*,\geq)$ would have the $infimum$ property, which is similar but dual to the previous one.

Comment: What is "the supremum property"? Does it say that every subset of $P$ has a least upper bound?

Comment: The property "every subset of $P$ is a least upper bound" is indeed equivalent to the property "every subset of $P$ has a greatest lower bound"; and a poset $P$ has those two (equivalent) properties if and only if its dual has them.

Comment: What is the supremum property? Regarding your proof, if you're interested in least upper bound of the whole poset $P$ and not just a subset, notice that it is enough that it has an upper bound, because if $p \leq u$ for all $p \in P$, then for $u \leq \alpha \in P$, it immediately follows that $u = \alpha$, by anti-symmetry of $\leq$.

Comment: The supremum property is "If every nonempty subset of $(P,\leq)$ has an upper bound in $P$, then it has a least upper bound in $P$."

Comment: In that case, the right conclusion is: if $(P,\leq)$ has the supremum property, then $(P,\geq)$ has the infimum property. This conclusion (and its converse) among similar ones, follow from the [Duality Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)).

Comment: @Mathguy.  The correct definition is:  For all nonempty set A, if A has an upper bound, then A has a least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

A simple calculation suffices,

```
   ⊔ is the lub in (P, ⊑)
≡⟨ definition ⟩
   ∀ x, y • ∀ z • x ⊑ z ∧ y ⊑ z ≡ x ⊔ y ⊑ z
≡⟨ Dual order ⟩
   ∀ x, y • ∀ z • z ⊒ x ∧ z ⊒ y ≡ z ⊒ x ⊔ y
≡⟨ definition ⟩
   ⊔ is the glb in (P, ⊒)
```

;-)

Comment: I do not understand this notation, is this code for a program?

Comment: The square notation is just the *name* of the order and lub and glb that I wish to use. You instead used $\leq$ for the order name. That is all.